# List of SE sites to migrate off-topic questions to.

Tags: discussion, migration

The list of StackExchange sites that appear when voting to close a question as off-topic is limited to a few. Currently the only option is the meta site. I think we should establish which sites are the most likely candidates for off-topic questions.

Post your site suggestions and let the votes do the talking. :)

Answer (score 12):

### Home Improvement - https://diy.stackexchange.com/

This one should be self-evident.

Comment: And should go the other direction as well.  I saw a question on DIY today asking about stump clearing, which probably should be moved here.

Comment: @Scivitri: That's only if this takes off beta...

Answer (score 8):

### Cooking - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

For those questions that fall on the eating and preparing side of vegetables/fruits, etc. rather than the growing/planting/harvesting side.

Answer (score 3):

### **Biology** - http://biology.stackexchange.com

For questions formal enough to bordering on the following branches of biology:

- botany
- genetics
- cell biology (of plants)
- physiology (of plants)
- ecology
- biochemistry (pertaining to plants)
- evolutionary biology (of plants)

Comment: Why the downvote? Thanks.

Comment: ^^ I agree. No good reason to -1.

Answer (score 0):

### Physics - https://physics.stackexchange.com/

I can foresee the occasional question about water, solar effects, and such that might go beyond the gardening/landscaping scope, and require more hard science.

Answer (score -1):

### Startups - http://answers.onstartups.com/

Questions relating to starting a CSA, stand, or getting into a farmers market

Answer (score -2):

### Motor vehichle Maintenance - http://mechanics.stackexchange.com

Questions related to fixing tractors?

Comment: Personally I wish Motor Vehicles was a bit more broad in the sense that it included small engine repair as well. I think it would make an ideal location to ask about fixes for engine-based tools such as tillers and mowers.

Comment: -1 Most gardening questions are very unlikely to be related to motor vehicles.

Answer (score -3):

### Superuser / Webapps - http://superuser.com

Questions related to http://gardenplanner.jungseed.com (point to appropriate site if it's a web app or standalone)

[Note, I don't think this is a good idea at all, I'm just wondering if questions about these apps are appropriate here]